# Email validation doesnt work properly

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code:

```
$checkDB = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $checkDB);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $errorEmail = 'This email is registered m8';
    $mainError = true;
}
```

So the problem is that it always says that the email is registered even if it is not  for the email check (email check is after name check). I tried changing variable names but it doesnt work.

```
$checkDB = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name='$name'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $checkDB);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $errorName = 'Name registered';
        $mainError = true;
    }
```

Comment: Email or username already exist in db

Comment: How do you set `$email`?

Comment: Not cleared u want to print name error first than email error

Comment: does `$email` = `email' OR email IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: Are you wiping your database between tests? Or using new data every time?

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_num_rows($result);` checks the numbers of rows of found email. And don't put `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`. I don't know why but its work for me.

Use this code

```
$checkDB = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $checkDB);
$check = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ( $check == 1) {
    $errorEmail = 'This email is registered m8';
    $mainError = true;
}
```

Comment: what does this rearrangement of current code achieve?

Comment: mysqli_num_rows($result); check the numbers of email.
and don't put mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); i don't know why but its work for me

Answer (score 0):

- You should check if it is greater to zero
- Fetching is not necessary
- Also in your stituation you should be preparing your statment.

```
$checkDB = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email= ?";
if ($result = mysqli_prepare($conn, $checkDB)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "s", $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($result );
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $errorName = 'Name registered';
        $mainError = true;
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```